# Sets - VENN DIAGRAMS MAXIMUM MINIMUM

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Among 80 people attending a seminar consisting of a morning and and an evening sessions, 61 participated in the morning session and 43 in the afternoon session. Find:

(A) the greatest possible number of people who participated in one session only
      [I've got 43 buts the answer is 56]

(B) the least possible number of people who participated in one session only.
      [I've got 0 but answer is 18]

It is very confusing.  Please if you can tell me also how the venn diagram would look like, i will be very grateful to you.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You've got a universe of $80$ people, and (possibly) overlapping circles.  In one circle are $61$ people representing the morning session and in the other circle there are $43$ people representing the afternoon session.  You don't know how many people are in the overlap between the two circles or outside both circles.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all participants at least did one session, I get that everything is determined uniquely:

$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$, where $A$ are the morning session participants, $B$ the afternoon ones. The union is 80. And we know |A| = 61, |B|  =43, so $80 = 104 - |A \cap B|$, so 24 people did both sessions.

Now $A \setminus B = 61 - 24 = 37$ and $B \setminus A = 43 - 24 = 19$. So 37 only attended the morning sessions, and 19 only the afternoon ones.

I'm not sure how to arrive at your target answers, or your own. Could you expand on that?

Comment: `not sure how to arrive at your target answers` FWIW $\,37+19=56$ happens to match the target number for (A), though not the question as literally worded. And $\,37-19=18$ but I can't fathom what question *that* would answer.

Comment: The question says the maximum and the minimum values.